# Android SetText not functioning

Tags: android, android-listview, settext

I'm trying to set the text of an EditText from a ListView. Once the user clicks the clickable EditText, it will then open up the ListActivity(That holds the ListView). When the user selects something from the ListView, it will then go back to the activity that holds the clickable EditText and change the text within the EditText(Hopefully that makes sense).

Problem I am having is when I click a product from the list, it then returns me to the EditText activity like it should, but it doesn't change the text of the EditText. I have been trying to get this to work for 2-3 days and still can't seem to find why this isn't working.

Activity that contains the EditText

```
EditText CPU = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView4);
    CPU.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent CPUList = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    CPUList.class);
            startActivityForResult(CPUList, 1);

        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == 1) {

        Intent i = getIntent();
        String product = i.getStringExtra("product");
        EditText CPU = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView4));
        CPU.setText (product);

    }
```

Activity contains ListView

```
        ListView listViewCPU = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewCPU);
    listViewCPU.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

    String CPUList[] = {

    "Products go here", "Products go here", "Products go here", "Products go here"  };

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, CPUList);

    listViewCPU.setAdapter(adapter);

    listViewCPU.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listview, View myView,
                int pos, long mylng) {

            String CPU = (String) listview.getAdapter().getItem(pos);
            Intent i = new Intent();
             i.putExtra("product",CPU);
             setResult(RESULT_OK,i);     
             finish();

        }
    });

}

}
```

Comment: Can you print in LOG this part -> `String CPU = (String) listview.getAdapter().getItem(pos);` (I mean the CPU string)?

Comment: I don't see anywhere you're telling the adapter to update. Before finishing, perhaps try calling adapter.setData() with the new value from the EditText view?

Comment: Another option is to use `i.getExtras().getString("product");` instead of just `i.getStringExtra("product");`. Before all that, you'll also need to check if the extras are present.

Comment: @g00dy How do I print in LOG, never done it before?

Comment: You do this by importing `android.util.Log;` and you log information with `Log.i(PRODUCT, CPU);` just after `String CPU = (String) listview.getAdapter().getItem(pos);`. Then you look in the `LogCat` after you run the application and you see What is this variable's value.

Comment: Thank you for showing me how to do that, and yes, that gives me back the selected product it states in LOGCAT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if (resultCode == 1) { //HERE PROBLEM

    Intent i = getIntent();
    String product = i.getStringExtra("product");
    EditText CPU = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView4));
    CPU.setText (product);

}
```

resultCode==RESULT_OK
and requestCode==1

Comment: When I use this, my application crashes when I select a product from the list.

Comment: use data.getStringExtra() and not getIntent();

Comment: What data would I be setting inside the "()" at the end of "data.getStringExtra()"?.I Have tried product and CPU in there and I'm just presented with errors.

Comment: data.getStringExtra("product");

Comment: I've tried that already and get the following error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Intent"

Comment: String product = data.getStringExtra("product"); This gives you error?

Comment: Changed some things up using your code and it now works properly. Thank you and everybody else for helping me out, much appreciated.